# converting ip to netplan

Tags: routing, ip, ip-routing, netplan

I'm trying to convert a set of `ip` commands to a `netplan` configuration. I haven't had any luck so far, and I'm not sure why.

My script for creating the bridge is:

```
# Create the bridge
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up

# Make eno1 the upstream connection for the bridge
ip link set eno1 master br0

# The brige needs an ip address. Give it a static one because I don't know how
# to give it one from dhcp
ip address add 192.168.1.2/24 dev br0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0

# Remove the old default root and eno1 roots. We'll send everything through br0.
ip route delete default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
ip route delete 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1
ip route delete 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
```

And the netplan configuration that I'm working on is:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enx0a94ef568c61:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24
      interfaces:
        - eno1
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.1
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
  version: 2
```

`eno2`-`eno4` are unused (they're physical network interfaces).

The boot sequence stops--it's probably waiting for `eno1` to get an ip address, and it never really comes.  If I wait long enough, the boot will finish. When the boot finishes, I can ping the internet and local hosts. `ip addr list` shows that `eno1` doesn't get an ip address.

I feel like my `ip` script has an implicit dependency on `eno1` already having an ip address, and that my netplan configuration prevents `eno1` from getting one.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've only added the `br0` definition and added `optional: true` to the devices. When I ran the `ip` commands, `eno1` already had a ip assigned by dhcp.